# Regular expression to include files in multiple folders

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have multiple folders (4000+) with files included in every folder.
What is the Regular expression to select the files in all the folders in Pentaho "Get a file with SFTP" step.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot put wildcard in the directory name, nor to make a recursive search (in which case you could write the wildcard in the path name of the files).

You may find alternative [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864376/how-to-read-all-folders-and-subfolders-from-pentaho-kettle-get-files-with-sftp-s).

Mind that PDI uses Apache's VFS almost everywhere. So you probably do not need the SFTP job entry. You may `Copy File` or `Move File` with their uri (spft://path/to/file) instead of their name. With the same trick you may also start the transformation `Input File` without copying it before.